Unable to use Android SDK in IntelliJ on MacOS
I'm trying to select an android sdk installed via Homebrew as my project's sdk in IntelliJ. I installed it via --cask android-commandlinetools and then ran
sdkmanager ."platforms;android-34" "build-tools;34.0.0"
yes | sdkmanager -licenses # to accept licenses

In IntelliJ, I selected the sdk root path of my project to be opt/brew/share/android-commandlinetools. It didn't prompt that it is not a valid sdk means the structure of the folder is good, but IntelliJ instead prompted me that
Probably SDK installed in '/opt/homebrew/share/android-commandlinetools' is corrupt

My MacOS is Ventura 13.5.2 and has M1 chip.
I tried reinstalling everything but still didn't work.
